# Java SPRING REST Как сделать динамическое обновление данных у клиента

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

Делал десктопный мессенджер на JavaFX, использовал самописный сервер. Обновление таблицы онлайн пользователей происходило так:

Пользователь подключился->сервер создает поток обновления->всем подключенным клиентам рассылаются обновления.

Как это реализовать в RESTful приложении? Разница в том, что в первом варианте я хранил все сессии клиентов в отдельном ассоциативном массиве, но рест сервер не хранит состояние сессии, насколько я понимаю...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, посредством самого REST api я не смог решить эту задачу.
Вышел из положения следующим образом:

1. Запустил RabbitMQ сервер
2. На каждого пользователя завожу новую очередь
3. Создаю RabbitListener у пользователей
4. Вуаля! Раскидываю инфу о подключившемся/отключившемся клиенте по всем очередям онлайн-пользователей.

Answer (score 0):

Вы правильно понимаете, что в RESTful подходе сервер не хранит состояние сессии. То есть он не хранит информацию специфическую для конкретного клиента.

Примером такой информации для вашего приложения может быть то,  какие сообщения от других пользователей данный пользователь уже прочитал. Это должно храниться на клиенте и он сам должен управлять этим состоянием приложения и запрашивать у сервера то, что ему нужно.

Информация же о всех подключенных клиентах не является состоянием сессии так как не является специфической для одного клиента, а является ресурсом (или скорее ресурсами) к которым ваше API дает доступ.

Comment: Информацию о подключенных клиентах можно получить через Spring Security, насколько я понимаю. Там есть информация об авторизации и логауте, но как мне инициировать отправку данных клиенту от сервера? Грубо говоря, я знаю, что пользователь авторизован и ждет информации, но не знаю где от находится, что бы ему эту информацию передать.